# Run consecutive Shell commands in Python-Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, environment-variables

These are some dependant commands i am trying to run. My expectation was it will change current folder to `abc` & list files.

Also after setting `z=88`, it will print `z`.

```
import subprocess
cmd_list = []
cmd_list.append("cd ./abc")
cmd_list.append("ls")
cmd_list.append("export z=88")
cmd_list.append("echo $z")

my_env = os.environ.copy()
for cmd in cmd_list:
    sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=my_env, shell=True,text=True)
```

But unable to get any output for `ls` and `echo $z`

Comment: The commands are being run in a child process. The changes they make don't have any effect on the parent Python process.

Comment: Exported variables are only inherited by children of the shell process, they don't go back to the Python process, and won't be inherited by another child of the Python process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with multiple calls to `subprocess.Popen()`. Each call creates a new child process, and changes they make to their environment do not propagate back to the Python process.

You can do it by concatenating all the commands into a single command line to be run by `bash -c`.

```
cmd = 'cd abc; ls; export z=88; echo $z'
subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', cmd], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, env=my_env,text=True)
```

There's also no point in exporting `z`, since you're not running any child processes of the shell that use the environment variable. Just assign an ordinary shell variable with `z=88`.

Comment: Are you sure that `stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE` and `capture_output` work together?

Comment: Not really, I just copied that from the question. I removed it. I also removed `shell=True`, which it not useful when the first argument is a list.

Comment: Yeah, i mistakenly added `capture_output`. @Barmar Is there any way i can split that command ? Because for example, let's say if first command ran successfully and second didn't then i should revert first commands results.

Comment: You can separate commands with `&&` instead of `;` so the next command only runs if the previous one was successful.